# No wordwrap in DIV

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my "TEST"-text into my `DIV` named `class="button1"`, but it doesn't work correctly.

http://www.allgameplay.de/images/img-html_text_fail.png

```css
#main-tabs{
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
}
#tabs{
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

/*#################################*/
.button1{
  margin: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #485EDF;
  -webkit-transition: 0.45s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.45s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.45s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.45s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px #FFFFFF solid;
}
.button1:hover{
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3,1.3);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.3,1.3);
  -o-transform: scale(1.3,1.3);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3,1.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

```html
<div id="main-tabs">
  <div id="tabs">
    <div class="button2">
    </div>
    <div class="button1">sadafhgsdfhgadlfk,gvadbkhgbsdakhfgbskjdfhbakjhfgvksjejdfhgvskjdhfvgksjhfgvjk
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But what do You need?? To cut overflowed text, to break word, or maybe make ellipsis???

Comment: “Doesn’t work correctly” is not a problem description. And “sadafhgsdfhgadlfk” is hardly your real content. What you can meaningfully do with text wrt line wrapping really depends on the real text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `word-wrap: break-word`, see fiddle

```
.button1 {word-wrap: break-word;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lh5nem6n/

Comment: Ahhhh,

Now it just work correctly! Thanks for help.

Comment: Why a downvote when Vincent said it does exactly what he need/want?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add a `word-wrap: break-word` style to your div:

```css
#main-tabs{
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
}
#tabs{
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

/*#################################*/
.button1{
  margin: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #485EDF;
  -webkit-transition: 0.45s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.45s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.45s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.45s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px #FFFFFF solid;
  word-wrap: break-word; /* This is the key */
}
.button1:hover{
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3,1.3);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.3,1.3);
  -o-transform: scale(1.3,1.3);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3,1.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

```html
<div id="main-tabs">
  <div id="tabs">
    <div class="button2">
    </div>
    <div class="button1">sadafhgsdfhgadlfk,gvadbkhgbsdakhfgbskjdfhbakjhfgvksjejdfhgvskjdhfvgksjhfgvjk
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could also make the overflowing text disappear by instead adding `overflow: hidden;`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the text you wrote. Your text contains spaces. change the text or add "word -wrap : break -word ; " in class " botton1 " .

HTML-CODE

```
  <div id="main-tabs">
  <div id="tabs">
    <div class="button2"></div>
    <div class="button1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi error consequatur harum nulla doloribus fugit, consectetur odio a at vero, doloremque, eius amet autem tempora vel laborum. In, tempora, aperiam?</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS-CODE

```
    #main-tabs{
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
}
#tabs{
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

/*#################################*/
.button1{
  margin: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #485EDF;
  -webkit-transition: 0.45s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.45s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.45s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.45s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px #FFFFFF solid;
}
.button1:hover{
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3,1.3);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.3,1.3);
  -o-transform: scale(1.3,1.3);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3,1.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```